# Checking the available file handles using Qt to avoid SIGBUS error

Tags: linux, multithreading, qt, qthread, qprocess

I use QProcess in a multithread Qt console application. During runtime I got about 250 connection threads, each connection thread uses a DB connection and executes a shell command with a QProcess object.

My `ulimit -n`shows 1024 (=pipes or file handles available). I think I am hitting the limit here, changing it would only defer the problem. I need a proper error handling for this (instead of a SIGBUS crash). How can I check the available pipe number, before I start my QProcess?

Thank you very much for any hint.

Spikey

**quoted code from qprocess_unix.cpp from the Qt sources:**

The code crashes at the line `FD_SET(childStartedPipe[0], &fds);`

```
bool QProcessPrivate::waitForStarted(int msecs)
{
    Q_Q(QProcess);

#if defined (QPROCESS_DEBUG)
    qDebug("QProcessPrivate::waitForStarted(%d) waiting for child to start (fd = %d)", msecs,
       childStartedPipe[0]);
#endif

    fd_set fds;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(childStartedPipe[0], &fds); // Here I get a SIGBUS fault
    if (select_msecs(childStartedPipe[0] + 1, &fds, 0, msecs) == 0) {
        processError = QProcess::Timedout;
        q->setErrorString(QProcess::tr("Process operation timed out"));
#if defined (QPROCESS_DEBUG)
        qDebug("QProcessPrivate::waitForStarted(%d) == false (timed out)", msecs);
#endif
        return false;
    }
```

...

**this is the function that calls the QProcess:**

```
void CmdManager::executeCommand() {
  shellProcess = new QProcess();
  QString cmd = "/bin/ls";

  QString argStr =      "-lrth *.tmp";
  shellProcess->start(cmd,argStr.split(QString(" ")));
  bool b= shellProcess->waitForFinished(30000);
  if (!b) {
      qCritical("ls cmd finishing failed");
      shellProcess->close();
      shellProcess->terminate();
      return;
  }

  if (shellProcess->exitCode() > 0){
      qCritical() << "cmd failed, error msg=" << shellProcess->errorString();
  }
  QByteArray result = shellProcess->readAllStandardOutput();
  QString resultStr = QString(result.data());
  qDebug() << "Result=" << resultStr;

  shellProcess->close();
  shellProcess->terminate();
  delete shellProcess;
  shellProcess = NULL;
}
```

Comment: If you are _certain_ the SIGBUS happens on that line, this has nothing to do with your pipes. If you get a sigbus there, the only sane reason for that is that `childStartedPipe` doesn't point to valid memory anymore.

Comment: Good point! but uuuh. I see. So I have to find out why QProcess or its parent is deleted too early? Is it correct, that at the moment its parent is the main thread (if I pass no parameter to the constructor).